# How to have solid colored bars in angular-chart bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using angular-chart (based on chart.js) to create some bar charts and am having trouble getting the bar styling I want. I want the bars to be solid colors like this:

[image: Desired Result]

But I can't figure out how to get rid of the alpha that chart.js adds by default:

[image: Actual Result]

My html looks like this:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <canvas id="outreach" class="chart chart-bar" 
        chart-labels="ctrl.socialChart.labels" 
        chart-data="ctrl.socialChart.data" 
        chart-series="ctrl.socialChart.series"
        chart-colors="ctrl.socialChart.colors"
        chart-options="ctrl.socialChart.options"></canvas>      
  </body>
```

And the javascript:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js'])

    .controller('myController', [function() {
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.socialChart = {
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: true
                }
            },
            labels: ['2012'],
            series: ['FACEBOOK', 'GOOGLE', 'TWITTER', 'INSTAGRAM'],
            // colors: ['rgba(237, 64, 42, 1)', 'rgba(240, 171, 5, 1)', 'rgba(160, 180, 33, 1)', 'rgba(0, 163, 159, 1)'],
            colors: ['#ED402A', '#F0AB05', '#A0B421', '#00A39F'],
            data: [[1178], [652], [1004], [838]]
        }
    }]);
```

Here's a Plunker demonstrating it: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1o8waDHaBiFTQcYE1JDG?p=preview)

I've found lots of information about using rgba notation (which for some reason gives me the wrong colors altogether) and fillColor (which I can't get working at all). It's hard to tell what info is for version 1 or 2 of chart.js.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"`

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-controller="BarCtrl">
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" 
    chart-data="data" 
    chart-labels="labels" 
    chart-series="series" 
    chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"></canvas>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
  ctrl.datasetOverride = [{
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
          "#ED402A",
          "#36A2EB",
          "#FFCE56"
        ]
      }, {
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
          "#F0AB05",
          "#36A2EB",
          "#FFCE56"
        ]
      }, {
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
          "#A0B421",
          "#36A2EB",
          "#FFCE56"
        ]
      }, {
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: [
          "#00A39F",
          "#36A2EB",
          "#FFCE56"
        ]
      },
    ];
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/TBv3FCbDzbpeKwuEriuw?p=preview)**

Comment: @Sajeetharan Have you any idea, How can i fill stacked bar chart ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Ya, sure why not .

Comment: i make for data = [[1,2,3,4],[2,5,2,5],[3,6,9,10],[5,7,9,22]] value and also set option have   scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }, just passed array of color as per same u. Sorry for no idea about plunker creation

Comment: create a plunker and share here or post a question

Answer (score 1):

I am using chart.js version 2 with angular wrapper, Doing the following edits helped me.

Changes - color takes argument in the form of rgba(R,G,B,alpha)
alpha = 1 : solid color, 
alpha = 0 :  Transparent color

In HTML :
`<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="barData"
        chart-labels="filter" chart-series="barLabels" chart-options="baroptions" chart-colors="setColors" > </canvas>`

In my Controller class, i defined setColors as follows :

In controller.js :
 `$scope.setColors = [{backgroundColor:'rgba(249,166,92,1)',pointBackgroundColor:'rgba(249,166,92,1),pointHoverBackgroundColor:'rgba(249,166,92,1)',borderColor:'rgba(249,166,92,1)',pointBorderColor:'rgba(249,166,92,1)',pointHoverBorderColor:'rgba(249,166,92,1)'},
{backgroundColor:'rgba(90,155,211,1)',pointBackgroundColor:'rgba(90,155,211,1)',pointHoverBackgroundColor:'rgba(90,155,211,1)',borderColor:'rgba(90,155,211,1)',pointBorderColor:'rgba(90,155,211,1)',pointHoverBorderColor:'rgba(90,155,211,1)'},
{backgroundColor:'rgba(120,194,107,1)',pointBackgroundColor:'rgba(120,194,107,1)',pointHoverBackgroundColor:'rgba(120,194,107,1)',borderColor:'rgba(120,194,107,1)',pointBorderColor:'rgba(120,194,107,1)',pointHoverBorderColor:'rgba(120,194,107,1)'}]`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the codes that I have made to make a bar chart with custom settings. Use this attribute **chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"** in the canvas html tag:

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar"
        chart-data="expenseData" chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" 
        chart-options="chartOptions" chart-dataset override="datasetOverride">
</canvas>


var setGraphDate = function () {
    var xData = [];
    var yData = [];
    $scope.Data.ExpenseRecords.forEach(function (g) {
        yData.push(g.PercentOfCompletion);
        xData.push(g.TspShortName);
    });
    $scope.datasetOverride =
    {
        backgroundColor: "#4E4EFF",
        borderColor: "#2E2E99"
    };
    $scope.labels = xData;
    $scope.expenseData = yData;
    $scope.series = ['Expense Graph'];
   // more options
    $scope.chartOptions = {

        legend: {
            display: false
        },

        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'TSP Burn Rate'
        },
        events: false,
        tooltips: {
            enabled: false
        },
        hover: {
            animationDuration: 0
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use RGBA where A is Opacity and set it to 1 which defines the solid color.
Ex:  `backgroundColor: [ 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)']`

Comment: can't you just ask me to correct the code formatting instead of downvoting correct answer?

Comment: @Mohammad Kanan I am new to stackoverflow and this was my very first comment ..you should have told me first but you decide to downvote it...Now your action will effect my Reputation.

Comment: Hmmm!! why you think _I_ downvoted your answer?! I did not  ... , you seem misunderstanding what is _editing_ in SO, .. people are attracted to edit answers especially correct ones to improve them (this helps you get up voted) while _low quality_ answers that do not comply with SO are usually _deleted_ .. _downvoting_ relates to _technical_ aspect of the answer (may be its wrong) .. while editing only used for formatting issues .. _technically_ I even don't know if your answer is wrong? you can put a comment and ask why your answer was down-voted? whats _technically_ wrong in it?