# How to color fill a stacked bar angular chart (Multiple data Array)

Tags: angular-chart

Given the following plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/v01Kei1oI7sfdas2dbwN?p=preview

How do you fill the bar chart? As you can see its transparent [image]?

I have tried passing the info in this question [How to have solid colored bars in angular-chart bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407982/how-to-have-solid-colored-bars-in-angular-chart-bar-chart)

using

```
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"
```

but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Issue https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/issues/696

solved my problem

```
colors: [
                {
                    backgroundColor: '#A2DED0',
                    borderColor: '#A2DED0',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#A2DED0',
                    hoverBorderColor: '#A2DED0'
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: '#65C6BB',
                    borderColor: '#65C6BB',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#65C6BB',
                    hoverBorderColor: '#65C6BB'
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: '#1BBC9B',
                    borderColor: '#1BBC9B',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: '#1BBC9B',
                    hoverBorderColor: '#1BBC9B'
                }
            ]
```